# Swift TableViewCell “>” sign disappear

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift programming. I am using TableView in ViewController. The “>” sign to indicates the details view of a record, which is on the right end of cell, does not appear. Please note that I am using the “Right Detail” style on Table View Cell. I tried to use “Custom” style (default), got the same result.

Please advise me in which circumstance the sign will not show up and how to get it back?

Thanks in advance.

Galen

Comment: Show relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell has property called `accessory type`
You should manually set it in code `cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator` or in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you so much.